# HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse throws unexpected exception

Tags: c#, rest, windows-phone-8, httpwebrequest

I am building a WindowsPhone 8 application that calls a bunch of REST service.
Services are tested and everything is OK, I also have some logs from my IISExpress server as I am here testing everything on my workstation.

My issue pops up when I'm trying to repeat a bunch of PUT requests. As I am testing, those requests are the same every time. The first answers OK. The second is meant to answer 401 UnAuthorized and according to the logs, it is OK.

`2014-02-11 14:29:24 169.254.80.80 PUT /api/UserData key=2a80391882dc4a29fb4419bd70861ef9&sign=220a5962580eb5690109b2602be75b5fadf508ce9f464e4bdfae33f4520f9729&addresses=True 1476 - 169.254.127.48 NativeHost - 401 0 0 60`
The problem appears client-side.
I've got this :

```
public async Task<string> httpRequest(HttpWebRequest request)
{
    string received;
    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)(await Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null)))
    {
        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            RequestFailed(request);
            switch (response.StatusCode)
            {
                case HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError:
                    throw new WebException(new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd(), null, WebExceptionStatus.UnknownError, response);


                case HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized:
                    this.IsAuthorizedProblem = true;
                    throw new WebException(new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd(), null, WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError, response);

                case HttpStatusCode.BadRequest:
                    throw new WebException(new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd(), null, WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError, response);
                default:
                    throw new WebException(new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd(), null, WebExceptionStatus.UnknownError, response);

            }
            throw new WebException(new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd(), null, WebExceptionStatus.UnknownError, response);

        }
        using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {

            using (var sr = new StreamReader(responseStream))
            {

                received = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
            }
        }
        RequestSucceded(request);
        return received;
    }
}
```

The thing I can't understand is that at BeginGetResponse level, I got a exception thrown with a message "The server returns an error :Not Found".
The big problem with that is :
- I can't handle the status by myself as it is encapsulated in a WebException that does not know `HttpStatusCode`
- The real error is not *Not Found* but *UnAuthorized*. My programme can deal with an *UnAuthorized* as it is what is expected, but this error is just caught by an upper function that says "Any error occures, please try again in few minutes".

Here is some information about the exception :

> GetAddresses->GetAuthRequest {System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
>   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c_*DisplayClasse.b*_d(Object sendState)
>   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0(Object sendState)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
>   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Sorry for that, just a bad habit I got by searching on google.